# how to make a button that changes the class of another element?

Tags: javascript, html, class, button

I need a button that changes the class of different elements, I tried this this way :

```html
<button id="class-button">class change</button>
<div id="title">this is the title</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("class-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("title").event.target.classList.add("the-class")
    }
</script>
```

and that failed.

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your developer console? Can you elaborate on how you reached the conclusion (or provide a link to the source on which you're basing your implicit claim that) that the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) returned from [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) should have an `event` property? Better yet, what do you believe `document.getElementById("title").event.target` should return? Why not just `document.getElementById("title").classList.add("the-class")`?

Comment: @esqew I am a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `event` property of an `HTMLElement`.

If you want to add a class to the element, get rid of the `event.target` and do simply:

```css
.the-class{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<button id="class-button">class change</button>
<div id="title">this is the title</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("class-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("title").classList.add("the-class");
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Because, unnoticed misclick

Answer (score 1):

So I see two issues with your code:

1. You don't need the .event.target as you are not looking for an event. This means you can remove the `.event.target`.
2. Also you have not closed your event listener which means it's missing the closing bracket (which causes syntax errors).

The solution would be:

```js
document.getElementById("class-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("title").classList.add("the-class");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.the-class {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Keep on coding!</h1>
<button id="class-button">Change To Blue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put your JS in the onclick parameter.

```
<input type="Button" value="Click Me" onclick="document.getElementById('YourId').classList.add('className');" />
```

Comment: Generally this is a stylistic choice, but using `on*` attributes on HTML elements is largely considered to be not preferable to [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice).

Comment: True. I just sometimes like it to keep the code minimal. But off course having all the code in a external file is probably better